# How to tell mosaic (mosaic plot, R, VCD package) to always print the p value even when using residual shading?

Tags: r, mosaic-plot, r-mosaic

When I make a mosaic plot with default shading `shade=T` the p-value displays under the legend

`mosaic(~ gear + carb, data = mtcars, shade=T)`

[image]

When I instead use `Friendly2` shading, I don't get the p-value.

`mosaic(~ gear + carb, data = mtcars, gp=shading_Friendly2)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach to this would be to use a different shader that contains the p-value by default (like shading_hcl) and then modify the color of that shader ( https://rdrr.io/cran/vcd/src/R/shadings.R )

So to make your example working with that new shader:

```
cars <- table(mtcars$gear, mtcars$carb)

mosaic(cars, gp = shading_hcl(observed=cars, eps=0.01, lty=1:2, h=c(260,0), c=c(200, 200), l=c(90, 50)))
```